# How does a 7- or 35-pass erase work? Why would one use these methods?

Tags: security, hardware, erase

How and why do 7- and 35-pass erases work?
Shouldn't a simple rewrite with all zeroes be enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd never heard of the 35-part erase: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method

> The Gutmann method is an algorithm for
>   securely erasing the contents of
>   computer hard drives, such as files.
>   Devised by Peter Gutmann and Colin
>   Plumb, it does so by writing a series
>   of 35 patterns over the region to be
>   erased. The selection of patterns
>   assumes that the user doesn't know the
>   encoding mechanism used by the drive,
>   and so includes patterns designed
>   specifically for three different types
>   of drives. A user who knows which type
>   of encoding the drive uses can choose
>   only those patterns intended for their
>   drive. A drive with a different
>   encoding mechanism would need
>   different patterns. Most of the
>   patterns in the Gutmann method were
>   designed for older MFM/RLL encoded
>   disks. Relatively modern drives no
>   longer use the older encoding
>   techniques, making many of the
>   patterns specified by Gutmann
>   superfluous.[1]

Also interesting:

> One standard way to recover data that
>   has been overwritten on a hard drive
>   is to capture the analog signal which
>   is read by the drive head prior to
>   being decoded. This analog signal will
>   be close to an ideal digital signal,
>   but the differences are what is
>   important. By calculating the ideal
>   digital signal and then subtracting it
>   from the actual analog signal it is
>   possible to ignore that last
>   information written, amplify the
>   remaining signal and see what was
>   written before.

Answer (score 9):

A single pass with zeros doesn't completely erase magnetic artifacts from a disk. It's still possible to recover the data from the drive. A 7-pass erasure using random data will do a pretty complete job to prevent reconstruction of the data on the drive.

Wikipedia has a number of different articles relating to this topic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_forensics

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before, magnetic artifacts are present from the previous data on the platter.

In a recent issue of MaximumPC they put this to the test. They took a drive, ran it through a pass of all zeros, and hired a data recovery firm to try and recover what they could. Answer: Not one bit was recovered. Their analysis was that unless you expect the NSA to try, a zero pass is probably enough.

Personally, I'd run an alternating pattern or two across it.

Comment: I imagine that about half the bits were recovered - they just didn't know which - um - ones.

I'll get my coat.

Answer (score 6):

one random pass is enough for plausible deniability, as the lost data will have to be mostly "reconstructed" with a margin of error that grows with the length of the data trying to be recovered, as well as whether or not the data is contiguous (most cases, its not).

for the insanely paranoid, three passes is good. 0xAA (10101010), 0x55 (01010101), and then random. the first two will grey out residual bits, the last random pass will obliterate any "residual residual" bits.

never do passes with zeros. under magnetic microscopy the data is still there, its just "faded".

never trust "single file shredding", especially on solid state mediums like flash drives. if you need to "shred" a file, well, "delete" it and fill your drive with random data files until it runs out of space. then next time think twice about housing shred-worthy data on the same medium as "low-clearance" stuff.

the gutmann method is based on tin-foil hat speculation, it does various things to get drives to degauss themselves, which is admirable in an artistic sense, but pragmatically its overkill. no private organisation to-date has successfully recovered data from even a single random pass. and as for big brother, if the DoD considers it gone then you know its gone, the military industrial complex gets all the big bucks to try and do exactly what gutmann claims they can do, and believe you me if they had the tech to do so it would already have been leaked to the private sector since they're all in bed with each other. however if you want to use gutmann in spite of this, check out the secure-delete package for linux.

Answer (score 4):

7 pass and 35 pass would take forever to finish. HIPAA only requires DOD 3-pass overwrite,
and I am not certain why DOD even has a 7 pass overwrite as it seems they just simply 
shred the disks before disposing of machines anyway. Theoretically, you could recover 
data off of the outer edges of each track (using a scanning electron microscope or 
microscopic magnetic probe), but it practice you would need the resources of a disk 
drive maker or one of the three letter government organizations to do this.

The reason to perform multipass writes is to take advantage of the slight errors in positioning to overwrite the edges of the track also, making recovery far less likely.

Most drive recovery companies can't recover a drive that has had its data overwritten 
even once. They are typically taking advantage of the fact that Windows doesn't zero out the data blocks, just changes the directory to mark the space free. They simply 'undelete'
the file and make it visable again.

If you don't believe me, call them up and ask them if they can recover a disk
that has been dd'ed over... they will typically tell you no, and if they do agree to try, it will be serious $$$ to get it back...

DOD 3 pass followed by a zero overwrite should be more than sufficent for most (i.e. 
non- TOP SECRET) folks.

DBAN (and its commercially supported decendent, EBAN) do this all cleanly... I would
recommed these.

Comment: Where do you see that HIPAA requires a DoD 3-pass? hhs.gov doesn't seem to indicate any specific requirement, only that "For PHI on electronic media, clearing (using software or hardware products to overwrite media with non-sensitive data), purging (degaussing or exposing the media to a strong magnetic field in order to disrupt the recorded magnetic domains), or destroying the media (disintegration, pulverization, melting, incinerating, or shredding)." - https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/575/what-does-hipaa-require-of-covered-entities-when-they-dispose-information/index.html.

Answer (score 3):

See: [Secure Deletion of Data from Magnetic and Solid-State Memory](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html)

Answer (score 2):

Advanced recovery tools can recover single pass deleted files easily. And they are expensive too (e.g http://accessdata.com/).

A visual GUI for Gutmann passes from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gutmannmethod/ shows it has 8 semi random passes. I never seen a proof that files deleted by Gutmann been recovered.

An overkill, maybe, still far better that Windows soft delete.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of the question, some of the answers here actually contradict real research on that exact atopic. According the the [Number of overwrites needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure#Number_of_overwrites_needed) of the [Data erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure) article on wikipedia, on modern drives, erasing with more than one pass is redundant:

> "ATA disk drives manufactured after 2001 (over 15 GB) clearing by
>   overwriting the media once is adequate to protect the media from both
>   keyboard and laboratory attack." ([citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure#cite_note-SP800-88-18))

Also, [infosec did a nice article entitled "The Urban Legend of Multipass Hard Disk Overwrite"](http://www.infosecisland.com/blogview/16130-The-Urban-Legend-of-Multipass-Hard-Disk-Overwrite.html), on the entire subject, talking about the *old* USA Government erasure standards, among others, of how the multi-pass myth established itself in the industry.

> "Fortunately, several security researchers presented a paper [WRIG08]
>   at the Fourth International Conference on Information Systems Security
>   (ICISS 2008) that declares the “great wiping controversy” about how
>   many passes of overwriting with various data values to be settled:
>   their research demonstrates that a single overwrite using an arbitrary
>   data value will render the original data irretrievable even if MFM and
>   STM techniques are employed.
>
> The researchers found that the probability of recovering a single bit
>   from a previously used HDD was only slightly better than a coin toss,
>   and that the probability of recovering more bits decreases
>   exponentially so that it quickly becomes close to zero.
>
> Therefore, a single pass overwrite with any arbitrary value (randomly
>   chosen or not) is sufficient to render the original HDD data
>   effectively irretrievable."

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of misinformation around this, though most of the answers I see on this page are correct.  I've worked in the data recovery industry for 25 years and have addressed this exact question an enormous number of times.
The "residual magnetism" hypothesis never worked in real life.  And back then, tolerances were millions of times looser.

If you still doubt this, remember that a rotational hard drive uses the same storage principle as an audio tape - moving magnetic substrate storage - and the audio tape that was recorded over a single time in the Watergate case has still not been recovered.

A single zero-pass wipe renders all the data on a HDD unrecoverable unless some malfunction or mistake causes the overwrite to be incomplete.  This was true even back in the days when Peter Gutmann released his paper (which was like a tsunami in the erasure industry.)  Gutmann's paper was pure hypothesis, it never panned out in reality.  Even in the days of MFM/RLL drives, nobody could recover from a single-pass overwrite.  It should be noted that **Gutmann patented the algorithm** that his paper said would be required to ensure complete erasure.  Presumably, every time erasure was sold with his algorithm, he got paid.  I am not saying there was intentional deception on his part, just pointing out that his algorithm, though there was never any evidence it erased better than a single overwrite, was patented and sold.

Please note that SSDs are different.  SSDs can (and often do) use a pool of sectors that are rotated in and out of use, so if data is written to an SSD and then "deleted" and the drive rotates the sectors on which the deleted file is on out of the pool, an erasure might not be able to reach those sectors because the firmware in the SSD has control that software can't override.  One way around this is to continuously overwrite until all sectors have been rotated into use.

The reason multiple passes exist is because hardware can malfunction.  If the drive somehow malfunctions during one pass, it's possible that not all sectors will be erased - however, most good erasure software offers a full verification, which basically reads every bit on the drive to make sure the erasure didn't malfunction.  With that, multi-pass overwrites are overkill.

And sometimes, data is so sensitive, it makes sense to go overboard in making sure it's destroyed.  For example, I heard about a drive that was erased by the military with a 7-pass zero-fill, then the drive was run over by a tank, and then the remains were buried in a secret location in a highly secured area.  Practically, the recoverability is about the same as a single-pass overwrite, but if lives could be lost as a result of the data falling into the wrong hands, then why not go for the overkill?